# How to express "match a word or another" without creating a group?

Tags: regex, go, regex-group

I'm trying to match this kind of strings with a regular expression:

```
{{location|
{{location dec|
{{location other|
```

so I came up with this regular expression:

```
{{location( dec| other|)
```

which works fine, however it's creating a group at `( dec|)`, which I don't need. Is there any way to do the same thing but without creating a group?

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Comment: Golang regexp - http://golang.org/pkg/regexp

Comment: @DaveC , any question can be answered by reading such or such book or documentation. But if you don't know what you are looking for to begin with (in this case the keyword, as I've just learnt, was "non-capturing group"), then you are still stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a group, but you can make it a non-capturing group by adding `?:` after the opening bracket:

```
(?: dec| other|)
```

Non-capturing means the group exists just for the expression; no back references are possible and group numbering is unaffected.

Comment: @hwnd depends where you're running it. In most (all?) app languages, no. On Linux command line, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `?:` to prevent group creation so please give a try to:

`{{location(?: dec| other|)`